# which way is better to create a deb file?

Tags: build, deb

I created a c++ library and now I am trying to create a .deb file.

There are 2 ways:

1. Short way: create directory with *.so and *.h files, edit "control" file and then run dpkg-deb --build ( for example [Building a Debian package using dpkg-deb](http://dbalakirev.github.io/2015/08/21/deb-pkg/))
2. Long way: using debmake, debuild and more.. (as described in [debian.org/..](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch04.en.html))

I don't understand what are the benefits to choose the long way (option 2)?